# Google Map multiple location without geo code

Tags: google-maps

How can i display multiple markers on a google map without having any geo code?

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [gmaps.js](http://hpneo.github.com/gmaps/). It's wrapper around the google maps api, but "*with a lot less pain and more fun*":

```
map.addMarker({
  lat: -12.043333,
  lng: -77.028333,
  title: 'Lima',
  click: function(e) {
    alert('You clicked in this marker');
  }
});
```

[Example](http://hpneo.github.com/gmaps/examples/markers.html)